# VB.NET How to write text to a .ini file?

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a program that will help users create a certain config file for another program that usually has to be done by hand.
The programs config file reads it like; 'This_Setting = 0/1 (Off/On)'

So I want to make it so that if the user ticks say a checkbox on my program, it will write in the text file '1' and if it is unticked, it will write '0'.

Another way I thought about doing it was having a text box, the user ticks the boxes they want, and then click a button and then it would paste the config code in the text box so they could copy/paste it. I personally think this would be a better option, but I still have not the slightest clue how to do it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Save it with the `.ini` extension in the file path.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place to get help with a problem with code you've written.  Requests such as yours generally don't get much positive response.  Start writing code to do this and when you run into a problem, post a question with the code that isn't working and someone will be glad to help you!

Comment: Did you at least googled the title of your question before asking it? There are many good resources in the search results.

Comment: Why an INI file versus My.Settings?

Comment: @Plutonix OP stated [s]he is modifying another program's INI.

Comment: Ahh, missed that part! @JustinRyan

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to create a file, then [`File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is probably what you need.  If it is a large file, you can use the `StringBuilder` class to build up the contents of the file, or if it is a small file, you can use simple string concatenation.  After you have your string, you can use `File.WriteAllText` to write it to disk.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional way is to use `GetPrivateProfileString` (or `GetPrivateProfileSection`) to retrieve INI settings, and `WritePrivateProfileString` (or `WritePrivateProfileSection`) to change them.

You can find the syntax at [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.writeprivateprofilestring)

Comment: I think he is just creating the .INI file from scratch, not modifying an existing one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the VB.NET code to write to INI file,

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
    <DllImport("kernel32")>
    Private Shared Function WritePrivateProfileString(ByVal lpSectionName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long
    End Function

    Private Function SetIniValue(section As String, key As String, filename As String, Optional defaultValue As String = "") As String
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(500)
        If WritePrivateProfileString(section, key, defaultValue, filename) > 0 Then
            Return sb.ToString
        Else
            Return defaultValue
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub WriteToINI()
        SetIniValue("default", "This_Setting", "C:\myconfigfile.ini", "1")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Reference: http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/file/pprofilebasic.htm

Answer (score 1):

This should be very easy. What you would want to do is use the following code.

```
FileOpen(1, "WHATEVER-THE-FILE-PATH-IS.ini", OpenMode.Output)
PrintLine(1, "WHATEVER-TEXT-YOU-WANT-TO-WRITE")
FileClose(1)
```

All you have to do is just change some things to make it suit your needs. First of all, on `FileOpen()` you want to change where it says "WHATEVER-THE-FILE-PATH-IS.ini" to your file path (make sure you have .ini on the end.) 
 
The next thing you have to do to make this work is change where it says `OpenMode.Output`. You use `OpenMode.Output` to *write* to a text file, you use `OpenMode.Input` when you want to *read* from a text file (you would use that when you load the application) and you use `OpenMode.Append` to just add text on.

 
Now there are some things you need to look out for:

1. When you use `OpenMode.Output` it actually clears all the text from the text file first and then writes the text you want to write.
2. When you use `OpenMode.Input` you can't use `PrintLine(1, "WHATEVER")` as that is for writing to the text file not reading - so it will just crash. When using `OpenMode.Input` to *read* from the text file you have to use `LineInput(1)` 
    
   For Example:

   `Dim bool As Boolean
   FileOpen(1, "WHATEVER", OpenMode.Input)
   If LineInput(1) = "1" Then bool = True Else bool = False
   FileClose(1)`

   This code will read the .ini file and if it says 1 in it then it will set the value to `True` and if it has 0 in it then it will set the value to `False`!

So here is the code after all going through all that!

To load the values:

```
Dim bool As Boolean
FileOpen(1, "WHATEVER.ini", OpenMode.Input)
If LineInput(1) = "1" Then bool = True Else bool = False
FileClose(1)
```

To save the values:

```
Dim bool As Boolean
FileOpen(1, "WHATEVER.ini", OpenMode.Input)
If bool = True Then PrintLine(1, "1") Else PrintLine(1, "0")
FileClose(1)
```

(don't forget you can add as many `PrintLine(1, "")` and `LineInput(1)` as you want)

Answer (score 0):

A Class for reading and writing .INI files easily.
I didn't make these.
Instructions

1. Put this code into your project.
   VB Code:

```
    Class INIReadWrite
 
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function GetPrivateProfileString(ByVal lpAppName As >String, ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpDefault As String, ByVal >lpReturnedString As StringBuilder, ByVal nSize As Integer, ByVal lpFileName >As String) As Integer
    End Function
 
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function WritePrivateProfileString(ByVal lpAppName As >String, ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal >lpFileName As String) As Boolean
    End Function

 
    Public Shared Function ReadINI(ByVal File As String, ByVal Section As >String, ByVal Key As String) As String
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(500)
        GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", sb, sb.Capacity, File)
        Return sb.ToString
   End Function

    Public Shared Sub WriteINI(ByVal File As String, ByVal Section As >String, ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As String)
        WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, File)
    End Sub

End Class
```

2. To read an .INI file
   Code:

```
ReadINI(File, Section, Key)
```

3. To write to an .INI file
   Code:

```
WriteINI(File, Section, Key, Value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, You should use {} code formating for code examples