# How to save the configuration on a MDI Forms Dashboard

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mdi

I'm creating a dashboard (in VB.NET) with multiple modules. Every module is a different form with different functions and settings and the user can create how many and how much of these forms he want. My idea is to make possible to save the general configuration of the Dashboard (example: forms opened, position of these etc.) to be able to recall it when the main form is closed and re-opened and obtain the same situation or change between different settings (different user can load it's own custom preset).

I've tried to serialize the list of forms that are opened but serializing MDI child Forms causes trouble.

All the Forms are ok and works with its own settings. I need only the way to implement this kind of "global settings save".

How can I do this in the most elegant way? (it's ok also a rough idea than I can try getting in deep on my own)

Thanks!

Comment: You could use an ini file see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516686/vb-net-how-to-write-text-to-a-ini-file)

Comment: When you say "serializing MDI childs makes me trouble" what exactly does that mean?  Are you getting errors, unexpected behaviors?  Maybe show use the code where you're attempting to Serialize and Deserialize the forms

Comment: I would create a CUSTOM CLASS to hold all the information about the forms and their related data, then save/read that using the [XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094027/save-and-load-multiple-values-with-title) class.

Comment: @Hursey using Newtonsoft Json Serializer with settings to avoid child-parent loop it result in a stack overflow exception so i think it's not the most elegant way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the position of all opened MDIChild Windows, you can enumerate the collection of Controls of the MDIParent's [MdiClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mdiclient) container (the Container that actually parents the MDI Child Windows).
This will give you the correct order in which these Windows are shown.
The [Application.OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms) collection won't, it just enumerates the opened Forms.

You can use the `Form.Name` as reference and save its [Bounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.bounds) Rectangle.
Here, I'm using the [RectangleConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangleconverter) class to serialize the Forms' Bounds.

▶ Here, I'm *serializing* just the Form Name and its Bounds. You can of course serialize whatever other properties / values you need.
In that case, you can build a class structure that stores the information and serialize it using a Json or XML Serializer (I suggest the former. IMO, avoid `BinaryFormatter`).

To also save the Bounds of the MDIParent, add it last to the list, since when you read back the list of Forms, you have to invert the order in which the Forms are created (the last created goes on top).

To recreate the Forms, you can use [Activator.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance), passing the Type of the Form to create.

The file that stores this information is saved in [Application.CommonAppDataPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.commonappdatapath):

```
Path.Combine(Application.CommonAppDataPath, "FormsLayout.txt")
```

It points to a **`ProgramData`** folder - dedicated to the calling app - of the drive where the System is installed. Your app always has write permissions here.

When the MDI Application is about to close (`Form.FormClosing` event handler), the `SaveWindowsOrder()` method is called. It will store the current Order and Bounds of all opened windows, MDIParent included.

When the MDI Parent is about to be shown (`Form.Shown` event handler), the `LoadWindowsOrder()` is called, to restore the previous layout.

Add these `Imports`:

```
Imports System.Drawing ' If not already defined in the Project's References
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq    ' If not already defined in the Project's References
Imports System.Reflection
```

**Public methods**
Add to the Form, to a Module or, if you prefer, add `Shared` and use a dedicated helper class.

```
Public Sub SaveWindowsOrder(filePath As String, mdiPparent As Form)
    Dim formsOrder As New List(Of String)
    Dim mClient = mdiPparent.Controls.OfType(Of MdiClient).First()

    For Each f As Form In mClient.Controls.OfType(Of Form).ToList()
        Dim sRect = New RectangleConverter().ConvertToString(f.Bounds)
        formsOrder.Add($"{f.Name};{sRect}")
    Next
    formsOrder.Add($"{mdiPparent.Name};{New RectangleConverter().ConvertToString(mdiPparent.Bounds)}")
    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, formsOrder)
End Sub

Public Sub LoadWindowsOrder(filePath As String, parent As Form)
    If Not File.Exists(filePath) Then Return

    Dim orderList = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Reverse().ToArray()
    Dim appNameSpace = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name

    Dim parentData = orderList(0).Split(";"c)
    parent.Bounds = CType(New RectangleConverter().ConvertFromString(parentData(1)), Rectangle)

    For Each formOrder As String In orderList.Skip(1).ToArray()
        Dim params = formOrder.Split(";"c)
        Dim formName As String = params(0)
        Dim formBounds = CType(New RectangleConverter().ConvertFromString(params(1)), Rectangle)

        Dim form = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType($"{appNameSpace}.{formName}")), Form)
        form.MdiParent = parent
        form.Show()
        form.Bounds = formBounds
    Next
End Sub
```

Add to the `MDIParent` Form:

```
Private Sub MDIParent1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Dim layoutFile = Path.Combine(Application.CommonAppDataPath, "FormsLayout.txt")
    SaveWindowsOrder(layoutFile, Me)
End Sub

Private Sub MDIParent1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    Dim layoutFile = Path.Combine(Application.CommonAppDataPath, "FormsLayout.txt")
    LoadWindowsOrder(layoutFile, Me)
End Sub
```

Comment: it's perfect, Thanks! Only a question.. I need to save also custom settings for each form. Each form has it's own Mysettings Structure but due to the fact that every form has its own functionality this class is different and of cours is not member of the general Form class used to loop all mdichildren. How can i access custom propriertes in that loop?

Comment: You have a lot option: e.g., if you have just a few Properties, you can bind a Project's Property as described here: [How can we change the background color of all other forms from one form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160815/7444103) -- Or use the code here to add these Properties (along with the Position, Size and ZOrder) to a Class object that you can then serialize (I suggest using a JSON serializer, very simple to use and manage) etc. -- You should post another question about this, since you need to add many more details. Link this question to integrate the context.