# Access property of a custom Form looping on Form objects

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Linked to this question [How to save the configuration on a MDI Forms Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66374258/7444103)
I have an MDIParent form that loops its children saving information. No problem on attributes that are part of the generic class "Form" but I can't access `.mySettings` because is specific of the type of each Form.

```
For Each f As Form In mClient.Controls.OfType(Of Form).ToList()
    Dim sRect = New RectangleConverter().ConvertToString(f.Bounds)
    formsOrder.Add($"{f.Name};{sRect}")
Next
```

Each form can be a custom class (ie: `myForm1`, `myForm2` etc.) and each one has `.mySettings` as attribute.

```
Public Class myForm1
    Implements IModule

    Structure Settings
        Dim opt As Integer
    End Structure

    Private mySettings As New Settings With {
        .opt = 1
        }
End Class
```

How can I loop on generic Form and than get the type of each Form and access its property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if the current form implements the IModule interface and CAST it:

```
For Each f As Form In mClient.Controls.OfType(Of Form).ToList()
    If TypeOf f Is IModule Then
        Dim m As IModule = DirectCast(f, IModule)
        ' ... do something with "m" ...
        Debug.Print(m.Settings)
    End If
Next
```